# What possible failures do I need to handle when invoking a RemoteAction?

Tags: apex, javascript-remoting

The [canonical example of invoking a remote action](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting_example.htm) shows three cases being handled:  success, exception, and general failure:

```
// just showing the handler passed to the remote action invocation, for brevity
function(result, event){
    if (event.status) {
        // do something with result
    } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
        document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
    }
},
```

Every example I've seen handles the else if and else cases identically.  I can find no documentation of what values event.type may be when event.status is not true.  Is this documented?  Is there any reason I should not eliminate the "else if" block, and handle all failures in the same fashion (i.e., log the error)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't usually do the `else if` and I use a lot of `@RemoteAction` -- if you haven't handled the error on the server side and returned some useful exception code than there aren't any other known (documented) `event.types`